# .NET Core 2.2 API Upgraded to .NET 6 Returning Only 404 Response

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

We are upgrading our solution to .NET 6 and everything is going smoothly but with our API we are running into a bit of an issue. I have the API building and running, but our front end is getting a 404 response and I can't seem to figure out the issue.

As you can see, I’ve tried a handful of common fixes to no avail. At this point I'm confident we are just missing some configuration in the builder or something new to .NET 6 that we haven't noticed yet, but I'm open to any suggestions.

Below are snippets related to the API structure, let me know if I can provide any more information. Please forgive the commented out code as I am continually trying different things.

Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var startup = new Startup(builder.Configuration);
startup.ConfigureServices(builder.Services);

var app = builder.Build();
startup.Configure(app, builder.Environment);

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.Run();
```

Startup.cs

```
...
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            services.AddCors(options =>
                options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins, builder => { builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:8000", "http://localhost:3000").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().WithExposedHeaders("File-Name").AllowCredentials(); }));            
            //services.AddMvc()
            //    .AddMvcOptions(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false)                
            //    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
            //    {
            //        // returning the string enum instead of the int value. 
            //        //options.serializersettings.converters.add(new newtonsoft.json.converters.stringenumconverter());
            //        //options.serializersettings.referenceloophandling = newtonsoft.json.referenceloophandling.ignore;
            //    });
            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup), typeof(AchFileParseMappings),
                typeof(ModelToResourceProfile), typeof(ResourceToModelProfile));
            //ConfigureSwagger(services);             
            services.AddJsReport(new LocalReporting().KillRunningJsReportProcesses()
                .UseBinary(JsReportBinary.GetBinary())
                .AsUtility()
                .Create());            
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostEnvironment env)
        {                        
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseCurrentUser();
            app.UseMiddleware<ErrorHandlingMiddleware>();
            app.UseMiddleware<ApiLoggingMiddleware>();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseRouting();            
            //app.UseMvc();

            app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
            {
                ctx.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Security-Policy",
                                         "default-src 'self';");
                await next();
            });

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseCors(x => x.WithOrigins("http://localhost:8000", "http://localhost:3000").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().WithExposedHeaders("File-Name").AllowCredentials());
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            } 
            else
            {
                app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
                app.UseHsts();
            }          
        }
```

Api Example

```
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Lockbox APIs
    /// </summary>
    [Route("api/v1/lockboxes"), ApiController]
    public class LockboxController : ControllerBase
    { ...

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll()
        {
            var lockboxes = await _lockboxService.GetAll();
            return Ok(lockboxes);
        }
```

Comment: Where you calling the URLs with `async` in them before?

Comment: Have you double checked to ensure that your route is correct?

Comment: @itsdaniel0 Yes, the api's were asynchronous before as well.

Comment: @LauraWhite the routes seem to be correct from everything I can see. I am continuing to try to figure it out.

Comment: @NacSquared What is the URL you're calling/hitting?

Comment: @itsdaniel0 https://localhost:44324/api/v1/lockboxes

Comment: If you generate a link via a Razor page using asp-link or @Url.Link, what is rendered?

Answer (score 0):

I will assume the route getting a 404 response is `GET api/v1/lockboxes/GetAll`?

Your route attribute `[Route("api/v1/lockboxes"), ApiController]` forms the base of the controller routes but will return the first `[HttpGet]` endpoint if it has no other parameters.

In your example, `GetAll()` will actually get hit by calling `GET api/v1/lockboxes`

To fix this, simply add a sutable route value to the `[HttpGet]` attribute for the endpoint.

In this case, for an endpint like `GET api/v1/lockboxes/GetAll`, your API controller would look like the following:

```
/// <summary>
/// Lockbox APIs
/// </summary>
[Route("api/v1/lockboxes"), ApiController]
public class LockboxController : ControllerBase
{ 
...

[HttpGet("GetAll")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll()
{
    var lockboxes = await _lockboxService.GetAll();
    return Ok(lockboxes);
}
```

You can use any aribitraty value for a route, as well as string parameters for basic values such as:

```
[HttpGet("somecustomroute/{lockboxId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> SomeMethodThatGetsASingleLockbox(int lockboxId)
{
...
}
```

The above would work for the route: `GET api/v1/lockboxes/somecustomroute/123`

For reference, you can find out more about WebAPI2 routes here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: Correct, so one of the api's being attempted is a GET for api/v1/lockboxes, which as you stated would default to that GetAll() method. I have tried explicitly declaring the route like your example above with "GetAll", but unfortunately have had no luck.